# How to show in Action bar, only if it can fit with text?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-menu

I am having the following buttons, with some ic_menu icons: `Register`, `Clear`.

I want them, in whatever device(smartphone or tablet), to be shown if they can fit, including their text.

If i use on both them: `withText|ifRoom`, on smartphone they appear both, without their text on portrait, and landscape with text.
On tablet they appear both with text.

I want them, on smartphone, NOT to appear if they cant fix with their text too.
Are any other combinations ?

Also what is `collapseActionView` for?

Comment: Read the second answer in this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282122/android-4-0-text-on-the-action-bar-never-shows

Comment: Thank you. So we found a bug on AOSP. thats nice.. unless we give up the icon