# Overflow item show only title doesn't show icons in action bar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, menuitem

menu layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_item1"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_item1">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:icon="@drawable/toolbox_item2"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_item2">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_item3"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_item3">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item4"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_item4"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_item4">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item5"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_item5"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_item5">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item6"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_item6"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_item6">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item7"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_item7"
        android:title="@string/menu_item7"
        android:titleCondensed="@string/menu_prev_item7">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item8"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_item8"
        android:title="@string/menu_item8"
        android:titleCondensed="@string/menu_next_item8">
    </item>
```

//items which have group inside overflow shows an icon

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/tools"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:title="@string/menu_tools">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/tools_group"
            android:checkableBehavior="single" >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/tools_item9"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_item9"
                android:title="@string/menu_item9">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/tools_item10"
                android:icon="@drawable/toolbox_item10"
                android:title="@string/menu_item10">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/tools_item11"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_item11"
                android:title="@string/menu_item11"/>

        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

//problem from here

//items which doesn't have group inside overflow items doesn't shows an icon

```
    <item             // from here doesn't show icon for menu item present in overflow
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:title="@string/menu_color">

    </item>


    <group
        android:id="@+id/page_group"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:visible="true" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/page"
            android:title="@string/menu_page_group">
            <menu>

                <item

                    android:id="@+id/page_clear"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_pageclear"
                    android:title="@string/menu_page_clear">

                </item>

            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/export"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_export"
        android:title="@string/menu_export">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_setting"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
    >
    </item>


</menu>
```

// I want to set icon with text for menu item from @+id/color to last one

Comment: You could use this for the reference
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000562/how-to-display-both-icon-and-title-of-action-inside-actionbar][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000562/how-to-display-both-icon-and-title-of-action-inside-actionbar