# How to display both of Icon and title in android menu

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I'm wondering how to display both of icon and title in android menu.

I'm using this :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.yasser.version6.NewprofileActivity">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_done"
        android:title="SUIVANT"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_done"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />


</menu>
```

Here is my activity, I'm extending AppCompatActivity is that fine ?, and then I'm using a custom toolbar for my application

```
public class NewprofileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView profil_image;
    Toolbar mToolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_newprofile);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mToolbar.setTitle("Profil");
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        profil_image=  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profil_image);


        Picasso.with(profil_image.getContext()).load(R.drawable.profil_icon).transform(new Imagetransformation()).into(profil_image);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_newprofile, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

but the title is showing only on landscape

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16754609/3713967

Comment: What else do you have in your menu. It could be that there isn't room to display both and I guess the text would get dropped first.

Comment: I don't have anything else just one item

Answer (score 8):

Use `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` instead `app:showAsAction="always|withText"`

And

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.Your_Icon);
```

Comment: I get an error " should use app:showAsAction for the appcompat library

Comment: @YasserB. Set now this app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"

Comment: Same no changes, I updated the post so you can take a look at my activity

Comment: @YasserB. getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.Your_Icon);

Comment: If not works the update your theme like <item name="logo">@drawable/your_logo</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>

Comment: It doesn't work, I don't wanna set an icon for my actionbar title, I wanna show the title of my menu item