# Display icon and title in the ActionBar in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to display both icon and title in the action bar of an Activity. Here is the screenshot of my app now:

[image]

Now I need the app logo be displayed to the left of MyApp text in the action bar. I have already tried the following code to set the logo but nothing happened:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher_web);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
```

Comment: Follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12000893/5156075)

Comment: have you done `getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);`

Comment: @ShreeKrishna: Yes already done that but no effect on the layout

Comment: Disable your actionbar in AppTheme then try again. I mean use this `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>`

Comment: @ShreeKrishna: there would be no action bar then to display on! the whole action bar will be gone

Comment: No, no you have to put that manually like
`<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"/>` and set ActionBar referencing that...

Comment: @Pooya ok I will add my answer...

Comment: use ToolBar for your customizing the bar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display both icon and title of action inside ActionBar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000562/how-to-display-both-icon-and-title-of-action-inside-actionbar)

Comment: @AmitVaghela : i have already looked into that. This is a different problem

Comment: @AmitVaghela It's about showing Icon and Text both as menu, I think it's not duplicate.

Comment: okay than in link i have mention is about what ? @ShreeKrishna

Comment: @AmitVaghela I didn't get you bro..

Answer (score 2):

I just tried with your code, and this works.

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

Make sure your parent theme is set to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: I have already try this. In this case only the logo is displayed in the middle of the action bar and there is no title displayed

Comment: Are you using a `ToolBar`? If yes, then that should not happen, because even I'm using the same.

Comment: No this is the default android studio file structure, I haven't add anything else to it

Comment: Still the problem remains

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new layout for Action bar and you could implement in main activity
Create new Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="60dp"
android:id="@+id/topHeaderNav"
android:background="@color/primary"
android:layout_height="60dp"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:maxHeight="75dp"
    android:maxWidth="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgTop"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/mag"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/topTitleText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgTop"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Magnetic Orange"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     />
```

and implement it in Main Layout

```
 `<include layout="@layout/navbar"
    android:id="@+id/topHeaderNavMainActivity"
    />`
```

I think it will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it doesn't show the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all be sure you have used style with `NoActionBar`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Set up your toolbar in `onCreate()` and be sure it's V7

```
Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Your toolbar in xml looks like

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"/>
```

And use those methods you have previously tried. This will work.

Comment: I tried it but the application closes and I got the following message from adb: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setLogo(int)' on a null object reference"

Comment: @Pooya are you sure you are inheriting from android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity

Comment: Actually i tried that before but Android Studio mentioned it as depreciated and suggests AppCompatActivity instead

Comment: @Pooya I have added some necessary attributes in the toolbar itself in my answer. Try replacing this code. Theme affects !!

Comment: I still get the previous error. It seems that there is something wrong when trying to get the toolbar resource

Comment: @Pooya It's really being hard finding out your issue.. Either you have multiple activities which are extending different activities or many reasons could be possible. Try extending only Activity in all of your activities you have and use the common theme I provided above. If you find another solution for this then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

if your require to customize a action bar then use costume layout in action bar, following was the code which explain how customize the action bar,

In your activity put this code onCreate method

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null); //hear set your costume layout
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#8731a0")));
```

it is the code which activiy inherit AppCompatActivity or if you are inheriting activity then replace getSupportActionBar() with getActionBar() and use.

Answer (score 0):

```
     private ViewGroup actionBarLayout;

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
            context = this;

            actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

            actionBarLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            // Set up your ActionBar

    /* final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();*/

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.green)));

            init();
            event();
        }

and used following style.

 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/green</item>

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Custom ActionBar.

custom_actionbar.xml

#### Layout XML

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
            android:background="@drawable/emaact"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="right">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Project"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/textView" android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.99"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/txttitle"
                android:text="title"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1.06"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menuline"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/slidingmenu"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In Your MainActivity, Use This code.

#### MainActivity.java

```
public void customBar(){
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

    TextView text =(TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.txttitle);
    text.setText("Home");
    ImageView menus =(ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.slidingmenu);

    actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

Your Action Bar looks like...
[Custom ActionBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGVoU.png)