# Setting title of the toolbar when a navigation item menu is clicked

Tags: android, material-design, navigationview

In my app I have the following navigationview.

[image: my app]

So when the user click the menu item Καλώς ήρθες(meaning welcome in Greek),I want the this to be shown in the toolbar. This is my code for the navigationview.

```
public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity {
private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private SessionManager session;
Toolbar toolbar;
private int mIconSize;
private String username;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());



    SharedPreferences userName = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    //UserId = userName.getString("id","");
    username = userName.getString("user_name", "");



    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        //Restore the fragment's instance and geo coordinates!
        //homeFragment = (FragmentHome) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mContent");
        setSelected(R.id.welcome);
    }else{
        //profileFragment = (FragmentProfile) fm2.findFragmentByTag(PROFILE_FRAGMENT);

    }
    ActionBarDrawerToggle adt = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,
            R.string.open_drawer,R.string.close_drawer){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(adt);
    adt.syncState();
    navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.navigation_bg_color));
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            boolean result = setSelected(item.getItemId());
            return result;
        }
    });

    View v = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView t = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.username);
    t.setText(username);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.log_out, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.log_out:

            logoutUser();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private void logoutUser() {
    session.setLogin(false);

    // Launching the login activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
public boolean setSelected(int selected) {
    switch (selected){
        case R.id.welcome:
            WelcomeFragment welcomeFragment = new WelcomeFragment();
            FragmentManager fm1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTra1 = fm1.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTra1.replace(R.id.content,welcomeFragment);
            //fragmentTra1.addToBackStack("added");

            fragmentTra1.commit();
        return true;
        case R.id.general:
            GeneralFragment generalFragment= new GeneralFragment();
            FragmentManager fm2 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTra2 = fm2.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTra2.replace(R.id.content,generalFragment);
            //fragmentTra1.addToBackStack("added");

            fragmentTra2.commit();
            return true;
        case R.id.announcements:
            AnnouncementsFragment announcementsFragment= new AnnouncementsFragment();
            FragmentManager fm3 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTraSubOne = fm3.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTraSubOne.replace(R.id.content,announcementsFragment);
            //fragmentTra1.addToBackStack("added");

            fragmentTraSubOne.commit();
            return true;
        case R.id.sub_one:
            NewsFragment newsFragment= new NewsFragment();
            FragmentManager fm4 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTraSubTwo = fm4.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTraSubTwo.replace(R.id.content,newsFragment);
            //fragmentTra1.addToBackStack("added");

            fragmentTraSubTwo.commit();
            return true;
        case R.id.sub_two:
            FanClubFragment fanClubFragment= new FanClubFragment();
            FragmentManager fm5 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTraSubThree = fm5.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTraSubThree.replace(R.id.content,fanClubFragment);
            //fragmentTra1.addToBackStack("added");
            fragmentTraSubThree.commit();
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
public static Intent newIntent(Context context) {

    return new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(isNavDrawerOpen()){
        closeDrawerLayout();
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public boolean isNavDrawerOpen() {
    return drawerLayout!=null && drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START);
}
private void closeDrawerLayout(){
    if(drawerLayout != null){
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    return (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ? true :    
  super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));
 }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `setTitle()`:

```
public boolean setSelected(int selected) {
    switch (selected){
            case R.id.welcome:
                toolbar.setTitle("Welcome");
                ......
            }
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title");
```

in the switch-case

Comment: as @Harsh Pandey says or use setTitle("title") directly

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, ID, POSITION, TEXT);
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.drawable_resource_name);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    return true;
}
```

Also this link might help: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000562/how-to-display-both-icon-and-title-of-action-inside-actionbar)

Hope it helps ;)

btw your app looks great!