# Force to show icon + text toolbar menu item

Tags: android, menu, icons

```
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_public_white_24dp"
    android:id="@+id/action_public"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:title="Public"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText">
```

I have this item, I am trying to force to show simultaneously.

If I remove the icon, appears the text "Public", but if I have icon then only appear it.

Is it possible to force to show both? I read a lot of info about it and this `app:showAsAction="always|withText"` should force this...

I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_public_white_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/action_public"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:title="Public"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText">
```

And it is not working for me.

I am in Android Studio 3.0 beta 5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000562/how-to-display-both-icon-and-title-of-action-inside-actionbar

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969172/how-to-display-menu-item-with-icon-and-text-in-appcompatactivity

Comment: app:showAsAction="always|withText"    it's Work For Me

Comment: @zephyr I added my main activity: <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"> and it is not working