# Android ActionBar don't show image and text

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I try to make ActionBar at bottom with image and text on Android 4.3

First I write main.xml file for menu

```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

      <item
            android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText"
            android:icon="@drawable/city"
            android:title="@string/home_icon"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_copy"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText"
            android:icon="@drawable/map"

            android:title="@string/mapa_icon"/>

    </menu

>
```

After that I put some lines in Manifest file

```
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                   android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
```

After all this I get Action bar at bottom but without text just images..
Also I try to put Button and textView on main.xml with drawable part and get same like first time.

Please any solution , or how to get icons with image on bottom ActionBar

Answer (score 2):

you can try

`android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` to show the menu title along with the icon.

the actual suggestion from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

> If your menu item supplies both a title and an icon—with the title and
>   icon attributes—then the action item shows only the icon by default.
>   If you want to display the text title, add "withText" to the
>   showAsAction attribute. For example:
>
> Note: The
>   "withText" value is a hint to the action bar that the text title
>   should appear. The action bar will show the title when possible, but
>   might not if an icon is available and the action bar is constrained
>   for space.

but this does not work in ICS+

for a detailed discussion on why this won't work:

[android 4.0, text on the action bar NEVER shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282122/android-4-0-text-on-the-action-bar-never-shows)

Answer (score 0):

try  like this refer this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView) to know how to add the view in bottom actionbar

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    // Configure the search info and add any event listeners
    ...
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```