# How can center an action in action bar with text?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I make an action bar like this: 
[image]

Add: 
My current implement:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_cancel"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
          android:title="@string/action_cancel"
            />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_accept"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
          android:title="@string/action_accept"
            />
</menu>
```

and it now looks like: 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking into action mode??

Comment: I have not. thanks for your advice. I'll try it now.

Comment: I googled action mode, but find nothing helpful. Can you give me a link for my problem. thanks.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282122/android-4-0-text-on-the-action-bar-never-shows

Answer (score 1):

Ok buddy. Thing you're looking for is known as "Split Action Bar".

Check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/) out, this link has multiple actionbar example. It also has "Split Action Bar" tutorial. It might not be the exact same thing you want, but you should be able to figure your way out.

Hit like, if this helps you out.

Let me know of any other question.

Comment: Thanks for your link. You are very kind person.
But I already know how to split action bar. But I don't know how to make action bar looks like the fist image that I posted. I mean that two actions will be centered and show with text.
Can you help me in this situation. I'm reading your link. 
Thanks.