# Action Bar not displaying menu item with both icon and text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-menu

Despite there being enough space in the action bar , only the icon is being displayed, even when I am using

```
app:showAsAction= "always|withText"
```

Full code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.ishaan.admin.notify.Profile">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:title="Logout"

        android:icon="@drawable/logout_icon"
        app:showAsAction= "always|withText"  />
</menu>
```

Comment: Does text appear if you rotate the phone?

Answer (score 1):

It is known thing on the Android 4.0 and discussed ealier

Your can find solution here: 
[android 4.0, text on the action bar NEVER shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12225863/1314217)

Answer (score 1):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_right_button"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="Text"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_1"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
</menu>
```

and in Layout create Layout File menu_item_1.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logout_button"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_toolbar_locked"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textColor="@color/PrimaryColour"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```